# reactjs make content appear next to sidebar

Tags: css, reactjs

When I call my SideBar component in `App.js` it appears on top of everything with the main page under it and I understand why it does this but I don't know how to get it so that the sidebar appears to the left of the screen with the main app component it right next to it.

Here is my code:

```
const AppRoute=({component:Component, layout:Layout,...rest}) => {
  <Route {...rest} render = {props=> (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...props}/>
    </Layout>
  )}/>
)

const MainLayout = props =>(
 <div>
   <SideBar/>
   {props.children}
 <div>

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return(
      <BrowswerRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <AppRoute path = "/dashboard" layout={MainLayout} component={Dashboard}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    )
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const MainLayout = props =>(
 <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
   <SideBar style={{flex: '1 auto'}} />  
   {props.children}
 <div>
```

try this maybe

you could also apply float: left on both the sidebar, and the main content elements, giving the sidebar a fixed width

or you could try css grid:

```
const MainLayout = props =>(
 <div style={{display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: '200px auto'}}>
   <SideBar />  
   {props.children}
 <div>
```

Comment: thanks both methods worked. For the second I just had to adjust the gridTemplateColumns to get rid of overlapping of the components. Appreciate it !